# Bluetooth will not find device unless I turn bluetooth off and then back on

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on some bluetooth code and the bluetooth adapter will not find the device unless I turn off bluetooth and then turn it back on.  I think I might be missing a step somewhere. Thank you for your time

```
 ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(uuids[0])).build();
BluetoothLeScanner scanner = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
scanner.startScan(new ArrayList<ScanFilter>(Collections.singleton(filter)), new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).build(), mLeScanCallback);
```

Comment: Insufficient code to analyze and hunt bugs. Consider adding all relevant code for this matter. In this piece of code I don't see anything wrong at all. Can you confirm that your `ScanCallback` implementation is getting called using logs. Also knowing the Android OS version might help to analyze the problem. Another point would be the ble hardware  check right before firing a scanning. Can you also confirm that the bluetoot is on at that moment?

Comment: Turns out that revoking nearby devices permissions for other apps solved the problem. I'm guessing I had a rogue app on my device that was abusing the permission. It would be nice if someone knew a work around for this scenario.